# How can I employ type coercion in x.indexOf(y)?

Tags: javascript

I've got an array of numbers, but I'm not sure if they'll be formatted as integers or strings. All will be valid integers, so I will end up with something like:

```
X = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

or

```
X = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'];
```

I'd like to use indexOf to check and see if another variable, which I'm not sure if will be formatted as a string or an integer, is contained in X?

I know I can use something like `X.indexOf(+y)` to coerce `y` (the variable I'd like to compare) into a number, and that I can go piecewise and convert each item in `X` to a number using `map`, but is there a way I can allow something like `indexOf` to do javascript-standard type coercion? (i.e. treat comparisons in `indexOf` like `==` instead of `===`)

Comment: are the numbers integers or floats or natural numbers, etc?

Comment: You can't in the method itself. You need to implement your own, or convert the array first. `X.map(Number).indexOf(+y);`

Comment: The numbers will all be non-negative integers.

Comment: @WillNewton: How does that make a difference?  There's only a single numeric type in Javascript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just write your own `indexOf` method, maybe called `looseIndexOf` or something:

```
function looseIndexOf(arr, value) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
    if (arr[i] == value) {
      return i;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Default JavaScript value comparison w/ `==`. Pretty simple.

```
looseIndexOf([1,2,3], '2');     // => 1
looseIndexOf(['1','2','3'], 2); // => 1
looseIndexOf([1, 2], true);     // => 0
looseIndexOf([1,2,3], 4);       // => -1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're not looking to get the index value and just if it is in the array, you could use filter and pass in the optional this argument.  Based on the length of the returned array (greater than zero) you'll know if it's in the array.  If you want the index, you're best off converting your array and search value to the same type.

```
X.filter(function(el){
  return parseInt(el,10) === parseInt(this,10)
},y).length
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need the index, but just to check if a value exists, you can use the [`Array.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method

```
x.some(function(z) {return z == y}); // true or false
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nXjW2/)

Comment: This helped me :) if you do need the index, you can add a second parameter to the callback function.

Answer (score 1):

```
function doesItContain( arr, textOrInt) {
    return (arr.indexOf(textOrInt) != -1) ||
           (arr.indexOf(parseInt(textOrInt)) != -1) || 
           (arr.indexOf(textOrInt.toString()) != -1);
}
```

Comment: Your first `.indexOf(textOrInt)` should be converted to a string perhaps?